# Flutter Text Overflow Animation to make the full text visible

Tags: flutter

How can i create text overflow animation in flutter.

I have already tried [animated_overflow](https://pub.dev/packages/animated_overflow) package

It only go back and forth and the full text is not visible

I want to create something like this

[image]

Comment: And what's the effect you want?

Comment: i want the text to just go like in circle as shown in the question if it overflows the container

Answer (score 0):

I would try out the marquee package https://pub.dev/packages/marquee